# Unable to get CSS and jQuery into the program output

Tags: jquery, html, css, angular

I've an admin template which is in TypeScript and it's output is working good but when I'm trying to integrate it with landing page template which is having CSS, jQuery, and other fonts, I'm not able to get CSS and jQuery when I try to run the server. Am I wrong at app routing or anything else.

Comment: Can you please show your files and code for the same so that we come to some solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Component based Css then you could use styleUrls metadata e.g 
  `@Component({
        selector: 'app-dashboard',
        templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
        styleUrls: [ './dashboard.component.css' ]})`

and for global CSS you can use **styles.css** at root of project folder and please make sure that **angular.json** Styles and Scripts property are updated with respective CSS and JQuery path.

Comment: Thank you. I got it

Comment: In landing page I've log in option and when I click on it . It is not navigating to the log in page though I use router links

Comment: When I use anchor tag, the log in option is showing but the link is not getting created.       <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/signin.component" routerLinkActive="active">LogIn</a>

Comment: @SaiGoutham3 Problem is with routerLink tag it has to be routerLink="/signin"

Comment: If the solution works for you .Please markup the answer